# Mathematica StackedList Plot error : An option must be a rule or a list of rules

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot the given equation as a StackedListPlot. It works normally when I use the Plot function but does not work when I use the StackedList Plot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhbOv.png)

I am getting the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoeIb.png)

Thank You

Tried changing the input for x-axis but nothing worked

Comment: Please copy & paste the text of your expression.  No one is going to copy out all your code from an image to try to help you.  Also note there is a stack exchange site specifically for Mathematica questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Docs show `StackedListPlot[{AListOfPoints,AnotherListOfPoints}]` Don't know how you think you are getting two lists of points from what you showed. Maybe try `StackedListPlot[{ Table[Your1stExpr/.params,{d,.01,2.01,.25}],Table[Your2ndExpr/.params,{d,.01,2.01,.25}]}]` which should give you two lists of points to `StackListPlot`. Note I used .01 instead of 0 to start `d` because of `d` in denominator blowing up. If you can better explain exactly what you want to show in that plot then I'll see if I can make it do what you are looking for.